# The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

Tengo el siguiente problema en mi Android Studio cuando intento hacer el 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' me tira el siguiente error:

```
The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
```

El build.gradle de mi App contiene lo siguiente:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.projects.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar este problema?

Comment: El mensaje de error ya te dió la respuesta. Simplemente sigue las instrucciones de ese link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver el error:

> The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated.

Revisa la documentacion oficial

> [Migrar de los sintéticos Kotlin a la vinculación de vistas de
> Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)
>
> Las extensiones de Android de Kotlin están en desuso, lo que significa
> que ya no se admite el uso de sintéticos de Kotlin para el enlace de
> vistas. Si su aplicación usa sintéticos Kotlin para el enlace de
> vistas, use esta guía para migrar al enlace de vistas de Jetpack.
>
> Si su aplicación aún no usa sintéticos de Kotlin para la vinculación
> de vistas, [consulte Vinculación de vistas](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) para obtener información
> básica sobre el uso.

Actualiza el archivo Gradle

Al igual que las extensiones de Android, el enlace de vista de Jetpack se habilita módulo por módulo. Para cada módulo que usa el enlace de vista, establezca la opción de compilación viewBinding en true en el archivo `build.gradle` de nivel de módulo:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Si tu aplicación no usa las funciones de Parcelize, elimina la línea que habilita las extensiones de Android Kotlin:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("android.extensions")
}
```

Despues de realizar lo anterior revisa como realizar cambios en tus clases

[Actualizar clases de actividad y fragmentos](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration#activity-fragment)